# How do I create two boxes to put content in them, next to each other?

Tags: html, containers

I want to create two boxes next to each other. I tried many attempts to create boxes to be next to each other but the code always pours outside the box. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: If you can share the code on what you have tried until now it would be great

Answer (score 5):

Like so:

CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">Lorem</div>
<div class="box">Ipsum</div>
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/tte8p/) to see the code in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can create by simply using "**`display:inline-block`**".
And if you think the height can differ for each box then use "**`vertical-align:top`**" along with that.

Please see the code below:
**HTML**

```
<div>ddbsakdyagdkyhasd<br/> <br/> </div>
<div>ddbsakdyagdkyhasd ddbsakdyagdkyhasd ddbsakdyagdkyhasd
    <br/> 
    ddbsakdyagdkyhasd ddbsakdyagdkyhasd ddbsakdyagdkyhasd ddbsakdyagdkyhasd <br/> 
    ddbsakdyagdkyhasd ddbsakdyagdkyhasd ddbsakdyagdkyhasd
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline-block; 
    width:200px; 
    border:1px solid; 
    vertical-align:top
}
```

Please refer to Fiddle:- **http://jsfiddle.net/e6WqU/**

Let me know if this works for you.

Enjoy!!